# Cost of glUniform1ui

Tags: c++, opengl-es, arm

I want to use glUniform1ui to give a running index to my render calls so I can index an ubo in the shader where my actual uniforms are.
How much overhead will this cause if I only set it once per drawcall?

I cannot use glMultiDrawArraysIndirect because I'm required to use GLES 3.1.

Answer (score 2):

In the [taxonomy of state change performance](https://youtu.be/-bCeNzgiJ8I?t=1946), updating a uniform is the least costly thing you can do. Changing UBO bindings is more expensive.

So you should prefer uniform updates once per object to UBO binding per object.

However, since you are using ES 3.1, which features SSBOs, it might be better to use them rather than UBOs, simply due to the amount of stuff you can access from an SSBO compared to a UBO.

Comment: The thing I want to provide to the shader is a matrix. There are about 30 different matrices and all drawcalls use a matrix from this set. It is currently provided via glUniformMatrix4fv which has a visible cpu overhead. So my plan is to create an UBO array of matrices that is permanently bound to every shader that needs it then tell every shader the location of its matrix via glUniform1ui. The UBO is then updated when necessary for all shaders at once.

Comment: @Desperado17: Normally, when people do what you're trying to do, the number of per-object data in the array is essentially unbounded. There would be one array element for every object you render; sometimes you render more, and sometimes less, but the number needs to be fairly arbitrary. Hence the suggestion to use an SSBO. But if you have a fairly small, fixed amount of data that you're certain will fit into a UBO, then that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Performance cost of setting the uniform should be negligible, but the indirect data lookup in the shader might be relatively expensive.

Given you are targeting 3.x I would try to use `glBindBufferRange()` which lets you bind a buffer at an arbitrary offset instead.

Comment: Because that would be slower.

Comment: Slower than a direct uniform lookup without any indirection, sure. I'm not so sure it would be slower than using a uniform to drive an array lookup - at least for some mobile GPUs array indexing can destroy some GPU-side optimizations.

Comment: Not all array indexing is the same. Array indexing for what purpose? In which shader? What is the source of the array you're indexing? And whatever array indexing might involve, changing UBO bindings on every draw call will probably be slower.

Comment: Given that a dynamic buffer offset is a recommended "thing" in Vulkan descriptor sets, I would hope that it's not too expensive in OpenGL ES provided that you are only changing the offset and not the buffer that is actually bound.